# jvm exits for unknown reason

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, exists

Openjdk version "11" 2018-09-25, Spring Boot 2.6.6 application, will automatically exit for unknown reasons. It appears approximately every half month to one month

Introduction to the situation:

G1 garbage collector, maximum heap memory 8G

1. It is not a Linux system that kills processes
2. No out of memory
3. No JVM error file generated
4. The springboot log shows that the application is gracefully exiting normally, while the springApplication ShuttdownHook
5. Checked the ready-made logs and did not find any time consumption issues with the business thread
6. MAT tool found a large object in the heap file, accounting for approximately 1.4G

When it should be crashed, the heap memory is approximately 70% used

Who has a troubleshooting strategy? Help, thank you!

I hope to receive my troubleshooting ideas or reasons for this issue

Comment: To add, this heap storage file is a program I wrote that automatically prints when the application exits elegantly, not generated by the JVM itself. Application exits are not crashes or ooms, so no files are generated

Comment: Maybe there's something within the application telling Spring to stop (e.g. with `/actuator/shutdown`)? Did you try using verbose logging and getting it to stop?

Comment: I have also checked the logs and did not find any interface request logs that may have caused the exit.
Could it be that the Linux system sent an exit signal to the JVM, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Not enough information provided. Exit code of the process? Heap analysis? Add details to the question editing it, not in comments. You could use thread dumps  to try to capture who is calling the exit, but it may not be easy.

Comment: Yes a Linux signal is possible and there are probably useful tools (`ptrace`?) for diagnosing these. However, I think you might want to reproduce it locally. You could try something like [Logging Linux processes which exit because of a signal?](https://serverfault.com/q/968713) or [What's the easiest way to detect what signals are being sent to a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/186200) for that. An example of something sending signals to processes might be systemd trying to stop its services if its incorrectly configured.

Comment: I started using strace to monitor the jvm process last week, and today the jvm exited, indicating that it exited on its own! exited with 0, I'm ready to upgrade the jdk and replace the linux machine, and see if I can still quit on my own. Do you have any other suggestions?